# CS50 "C" loop incrementation with "if" condition produce wrong outcome

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, increment, cs50

I'm trying to learn coding from beginning by CS50. Currently i'm writing program called "runoff". Here's the description in short:
Program is an algorithm for determining the winner of an election.
There is max 9 candidates and max 100 voters.
Each voter submit their candidates in order for example:
Voter 1:
Rank 1: Charlie
Rank 2: Alice
Rank 3: Bob
Algorithm now gives votes (points) for every voters 1st rank (here lays my problem).
Next if no one wins (> 50% vote), candidate with least votes (points) is eliminated. That means, he is also removed from every rank 1 in every vote he is on, and the candidate form rank 2 advance to rank 1.
Algorithm repeats until we have a winner or there is a tie.

I already have the proper solution and code, but I have no clue why my implementation is wrong. If you could explain it to me, I would really appreciate it!
The problem lies in tabulate function.

EDIT: // added code. thought the link is permament :(

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", 
        MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
       {
       printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
       return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) // test for 
        tabulate
        {
            printf("Candidate: %s, get %i votes.\n", 
            candidates[i].name, candidates[i].votes);
        }

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
             {
                 if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                 {
                     printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                 }
             }
             break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
             candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
return 0;
}

 // Record preference if vote is valid
 bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            for (int j = 1; j < rank; j++)
            {
                 if (preferences[voter][rank] == 
                 preferences[voter][j])
                 {
                      return false;
                 }
            }
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
void tabulate(void)
{
     /*for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < candidate_count; k++)
            {
                if ((preferences[i][j] == k) && 
                (!candidates[k].eliminated)) 
                // why this method doesnt work? :(
                {
                    candidates[k].votes++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
return;*/

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            int k = preferences[i][j];
            if (!candidates[k].eliminated)
            {
                candidates[k].votes++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
         if (candidates[i].votes > (voter_count / 2))
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has
int find_min(void)
{
    int minimum = voter_count;
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++ )
    {
        if((minimum > candidates[i].votes) && 
        (!candidates[i].eliminated))
        {
            minimum = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    return minimum;
}

// Return true if the election is tied between all candidates, 
false otherwise
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if ((!candidates[i].eliminated) && (candidates[i].votes 
        != min))
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Eliminate the candidate (or candidates) in last place
void eliminate(int min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(candidates[i].votes == min)
        {
            candidates[i].eliminated = 1;
        }
    }
    return;
}


if ((preferences[i][j] == k) && (!candidates[k].eliminated))
{
candidates[k].votes++;
}
```

I thought they have the same effect

```
int k = preferences[i][j];
if (!candidates[k].eliminated)
{
candidates[k].votes++;
}
```

What am I missing? Why 1st soution gives every candidates every vote and the 2nd solution gives vote only for the first rank?

Comment: the first statement uses a comparison (`==`), while the second uses an assignment (`=`)

Comment: Your link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/code50/8266540/main/runoff/runoff.c?token=GHSAT0AAAAAACAGXSFLJO25Z7ZLV4PRB53SZB734FA is broken

Comment: I changed it, im sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Lets single out the two parts and how they are different.

`preferences[i][j] == k`

and

`int k = preferences[i][j];`

The first one is a **comparison**. It uses the `==` operator to compare two values for equality, and results in a boolean value, either `true` or `false`.

Depending on what the values of your variables are, your code may do the following:

`one_variable == other_variable` turns into `4 == 5`, which turns into `false`.

`one_variable == other_variable` turns into `7 == 7`, which turns into `true`

The second is an **assignment**. It uses the `=` operator to give a variable a value.

```c
// k does not exist

int k; // k's value is ??? (definition of k)

k = 5; // k's value is 5   (assignment to k)


// p does not exist

int p = 7; // p's value is 7 (definition and also assignment of p)
```

As you can see, setting a variable does not compare anything.

So in the first example

```c
if ((preferences[i][j] == k) && (!candidates[k].eliminated)) { ... }
```

You are testing if `preferences[i][j]` and `k` are equal, and also testing if `candidates[k].eliminated` is false (that's what the `!` in front of that part means, instead of testing for true, that flips it around to test for false). Only then does the body of the if-statement get executed.

In the second example:

```c
int k = preferences[i][j];
if (!candidates[k].eliminated) { ... }
```

You are first setting the value of `k` to be the same as the value of `preferences[i][j]`, and after that you are testing if `candidates[k].eliminated` is false. Notice that `preferences[i][j]` and `k` were never compared.

So you went from **doing 2 tests**, to **setting a variable and only doing 1 test**. In fact, by setting `k` to a different value, the result of `candidates[k].eliminated` is probably different, because it uses `k`, which now has a different value than before. So not only did you miss out on one of the tests, you invalidated the second test.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I thought my link with code was permament :( I know the difference beetwen '==' compare and '=' asignment. As you can now see in my code preferences[j][k] has already a value, so i should be able to compare if this value is the same as candidate[k]. So im almost positive  as you mentioned it in first example, it should get executed properly.

Comment: Looking at your tabulate function, your commented out example has a third loop. The break statement in that one breaks out of the k-loop, not the j-loop like in the uncommented part of the function. Your i-loop keeps going in both though, I don't know if that is intentional. If you want to exit that one too then you should just replace the break with a return statement.

Comment: @TomaszSolga I forgot to tag you so by now you may have figured it out but I put the solution to your problem in the comment above this one

Answer (score 0):

The first code *uses* the value of `k`, such that `preferences[i][j] == k` may not be true; the second *assigns* `k` a value (forcing `preferences[i][j] == k` to be true).

Comment: Exactly, because it should be not always true.